# What does 'Se vende solo por renovación' mean?

Tags: expresiones, significado, chile

I have seen `Se vende solo por renovación`  on lots of sites similar to ebay.

What does this mean? Does it mean the product needs to be repaired?

This is Chilean spanish, if that matters.

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but I believe it means something like "I'm only selling it because I bought a new one".

Comment: That sentence uses a form of `se` called "se impersonal". We have [plenty of questions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=se+impersonal) about it on this site. You could also check the RAE for more about the [se impresonal](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables). [Renovar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VxzEmHC) indeed means `renew`. They just got a newer/better one and they are selling the current/older one.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I'd like to know if it means that the item is being sold for parts. (I.e. it doesn't work but the parts could be recycled.)  Or maybe it means "refurbished"?

Comment: @aparente001 my understanding is that something is being sold not because it is old, but because the house/office/whatever is being renovated, so the piece is now obsolete to the new styling. Imagine a blue sofa, for example, that cannot fit in a house that is being painted red.

Comment: @fedorqui - How does that fit for electronics, though?

Comment: I'm voting for reopening too. I'm a native Spanish speaker and I have never seen this before. I'd like to know what Chileans mean by that so closing it because of lack of effort should be forgiven this time.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't see any reference about electronics in the question.

Comment: @fedorqui - I googled the phrase and found it used for electronic devices offered for sale.

Answer (score 3):

Like others mentioned before, it means the owner is selling the item because he or she got a better one. This is the usual case when you purchase a new phone while your current one is already working. You put it on sale and remark that you are selling it because you got a newer and better one, and not because it has any defect or is not working, so potential buyers feel more confident.

Comment: I would add that it is a **marketing phrase**. Since it usually indicates that the product should have an **important discount**, although not always so.